# Change the order of an nested content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a Rails application to create questions according to the category. 
When editing my question I would like to be able to choose the order in which the question appears

[image]

---

[show image bdd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxxIy.png)

the column sort is identical to question_id but me question is a nested of category so i want the sort for the sub-ressource
And when I drag and drop an element the column sort don't change so when I refrech the order is the same

Comment: I don't seem to find any question here. What's blocking you, Léo?

Comment: Maybe you mean this? http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 'rails_sortable' gem might be the solution you are looking for. It is a wrapper gem for jquery sortable library(https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

It will allow you to reorder question by drag and drop.

Add the following gems to your gem file and run bundle install

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rails_sortable'
```

Add the following require statements to application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/sortable
//= require rails_sortable
```

Now you need to add sort a column to your Question model(I am assuming here your model name is Question) say 'sort' or 'position'. This will be the position/order of a particular question

And then add the following to your Question.rb(model) file

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  include RailsSortable::Model
  set_sortable :sort  # Indicate a sort column
  # If you do NOT want timestamps to be updated on sorting, use the 
  following option.
  # set_sortable :sort, without_updating_timestamps: true
end
```

While fetching the question data in the controller, order it based on the sort column

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.order(:sort).all
  end
end
```

And in the view,

```
<table>
  <tbody class="sortable">  <!-- sortable target -->
    <% @questions.each_with_sortable_id do |question, sortable_id| %>
      <tr id="<%= sortable_id %>">  <!-- Needs id tag on sorting 
      elements -->
       <td><%= question.id %></td>
       <td><%= question.content %></td>
       <td><%= question.category_id %></td>
       <td><%= question.sort %></td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And finally in the javascript file,

```
$(function() {
 $('.sortable').railsSortable(); 
});
```

rails_sortable github page: https://github.com/itmammoth/rails_sortable

Comment: thanks for this informations, I have followed many tutorials as well as this one but a problem persists when I refresh my page the elements are put back in the wrong order (updated at).
And when I look at my database all the elements of the table come out empty...

Comment: Could you share your code so that I can better assist you?@Léo-PaulDubourg

Comment: The github link would be helpful @Léo-PaulDubourg

Comment: Project [link](https://github.com/LeoPaulD/rpdad/tree/votes) ``https://github.com/LeoPaulD/rpdad/tree/votes``

Comment: @PrasathRajasekaran Yes I have create powerpoint for that, I'm a noob on stackoverflow... google slides. I can show you my github if you want. https://github.com/LeoPaulD/rpdad/tree/votes